# How to add a class while creating html comparing the data in a JSON array

Tags: jquery

The name value in the JSON has got the values as

```
826_ZZ_0_ZZ_0tab1_checkbox
826_ZZ_0_ZZ_0tab2_checkbox
```

In the above

**tab1** referes to the first quantity and 
**tab2** referes to the second quantity respectively

While creating the ulhtml , i need to check the name (**tab** followed by **number**) in the JSON , if it has got corresponding tab i need to add the class active to it

This is my program

```
var addonsQtyWrap = $('<div class="addonsQtyWrap"></div>');

var json = [
    {
        "name": "826_ZZ_0_ZZ_0tab1_checkbox",
        "cost": 100,
        "additionname": "Choco chips",
        "addtionid": 59
    },
    {
        "name": "826_ZZ_0_ZZ_0tab2_checkbox",
        "cost": 100,
        "additionname": "Choco chips",
        "addtionid": 59
    }
] ;

var quantity = 3;
var ulhtml = '<ul>';
for (var i = 1; i <= quantity; i++) {
        if (i == 1) {
            ulhtml += '<li    data-tabid="' + i + '"   class="tabclcik">Qty-' + i + '</li>';
        } else {
            ulhtml += '<li   data-tabid="' + i + '" class="tabclcik">Qty-' + i + '</li>';
        }
    };

addonsQtyWrap.append(ulhtml);
$("#header").append(addonsQtyWrap);


For example in this program there are tab1 and tab2 in the JSON so i want to add class active to the tab1 and tab2



for (var i = 1; i <= quantity; i++) {
        if (i == 1) {
            ulhtml += '<li    data-tabid="' + i + '"   class="tabclcik active">Qty-' + i + '</li>';
        } else {
            ulhtml += '<li   data-tabid="' + i + '" class="tabclcik active">Qty-' + i + '</li>';
        }
    };
```

i have tried as shown in this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/19/

But i am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

could anybody please let me know how to resolve this ??

Answer (score 0):

In the following for loop

```
for (var i = 1; i <= quantity; i++) {
```

You're looping from values from 1 to 3 (included) but since you've only 2 elements in json,  `json[2]` will give you error.

Correct your looping to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
 var quantity=2;
 var ulhtml = '<ul>';
 for (var i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
 if (i == 1) {
     var itemname = json[i].name.indexOf("tab" + 1);
     if (itemname !== -1) {
         ulhtml += '<li    data-tabid="' + i + '"   class="tabclcik active">Qty-' + i + '</li>';
     } else {
         ulhtml += '<li    data-tabid="' + i + '"   class="tabclcik">Qty-' + i + '</li>';
     }

 } else {
     var itemname = json[i].name.indexOf("tab" + (i+1));

     if (itemname !== -1) {
         ulhtml += '<li    data-tabid="' + i + '"   class="tabclcik active">Qty-' + i + '</li>';
     } else {
         ulhtml += '<li    data-tabid="' + i + '"   class="tabclcik">Qty-' + i + '</li>';
     }

 }};
 addonsQtyWrap.append(ulhtml);
 $("#header").append(addonsQtyWrap);
```

### Working Demo

Comment: Thank you but the quantity and the json array might have different lengths

Comment: I was trying to push the elements (names) in a temporary array and then try to compare them , but i am facing issues .

Comment: you can replace with actual quantity number in for loop(the place where i have hardcoded 2)

Comment: But then the problem will b it will not create those many quantities know .

Comment: For example in the jsfiddle you posted i have 3 quantity and and 2 elemnets under json array , but it is creating only 2 quantites know .

Comment: @Kiran: not sure what you are you trying to say.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion , i wanted to resolve it this way http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/20/

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you have quantity = 3, but you only have 2 items in your json object. It's erring on the third iteration.

Try any of these:

```
//1
for (var i = 1; i < quantity; i++) {}

//2
for (var i = 1, len = json.length; i <= len; i++) {}

//3
var quantity = 2;
for (var i = 1; i <= quantity; i++) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get "Undefined", because you try to reference the THIRD element of your JSON array (quantity = 3) when you only have two. Also, your Fiddle code differs from the above, which makes the question confusing.